# Collision detection Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, collision

I'm trying to detect a collision between two Xamarin. Forms Controls (BoxViews), but I can't find a way to do it. I have a button that what it does is to decrease the TranslationY of a BoxView until it collides with the other BoxView. I remember that with WinForms this could be done with IntersectsWith, but apparently here does not work, I currently have this:

```
public class Main : ContentPage
{
    public BoxView pjOne = new BoxView { BackgroundColor = Color.Red, HeightRequest = 100, WidthRequest = 100, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand };
    public BoxView pjTwo = new BoxView { BackgroundColor = Color.Green, HeightRequest = 100, WidthRequest = 100, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand };
    public Button btnDown = new Button { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End, Text = "Down", TextColor = Color.White };

    public Main()
    {
        btnDown.Clicked += (s, e) =>
        {
            if(!pjOne.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pjTwo.Bounds))
            {
                pjOne.TranslationY -= 100; //If it does not detect collision it decreases the TranslationY
            }
            else
            {
                pjOne.TranslationY += 100; //If it detects collision it increases the TranslationY
            }
        };

        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children =
            {
                pjOne,
                pjTwo,
                btnDown
            }
        };
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work, it never detects the collision between the two BoxView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bounds do not get updated when a Translation is applied.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.bounds?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_VisualElement_Bounds):

**Bounds is assigned during the Layout cycle by a call to Layout(Rectangle).**

I would try

1. calling [Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.layout?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_VisualElement_Layout_Xamarin_Forms_Rectangle_) with the new location you want to translate the BoxView to
2. create a rectangle for pjOne and pjTwo. Then you could use the [Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle.IntercectsWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.rectangle.intersectswith?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Rectangle_IntersectsWith_Xamarin_Forms_Rectangle_) method.

Here is an untested example of how to do this:

```
var pjRectOne = new Rectangle(pjOne.X + pjOne.TranslationX, pjOne.Y + pjOne.TranslationY, pjOne.Width, pjOne.Height);
var pjRectTwo = new Rectangle(pjTwo.X + pjTwo.TranslationX, pjTwo.Y + pjTwo.TranslationY, pjTwo.Width, pjTwo.Height);
if (pjRectOne.IntercectsWith(pjRectTwo))
{

}
```

**Note**: if pjOne or pjTwo are children of a view, their X and Y positions will be relative to the parent. To get the absolute X and Y, [loop through all their parents](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/24042/how-can-i-get-absolute-position-of-element-view-in-xamarin-forms) by doing something like this

```
var y = pjOne.Y; 
var parent = pjOne.ParentView; 
while (parent != null) 
{ 
    y += parent.Y; 
    parent = parent.ParentView; 
}
```

Hope this helped you out :)